# Can't write message to SQS using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, boto3

I'm using boto3, AWS library to connect to their SQS services. I'm trying to connect, read and write messages from a queue but this doesn't seem to be working and the documentation isn't helping

here's my code, anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
#Connect to a session
session = Session(aws_access_key_id=SQSAccessKey, aws_secret_access_key=SQSSecretKey,region_name=sqsRegion)

#Connect to a resource
sqs= session.resource('sqs')

queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=transactionQueue)
print(queue.url)

# Create a new message
print 'creating new message'
toWrite = 'hello world'
response = queue.send_message(MessageBody=toWrite)
print(response.get('MessageId'))

#Reading messages in queue
messages = queue.receive_messages()
print 'there are %s messages in the queue' % len(messages)
for message in messages:
    # SQS Message
    message.body
    message.delete()
```

After sending the new message to the queue (and printing out the message ID) I try to read the queue for messages but it returns no new messages as if nothing was written to it.

Anything I'm doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: Do you have delay set on the queue? Do you have any other client polling the queue in the same time?

Comment: No delay and no other client polling the queue:
{'ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible': '0', 'RedrivePolicy': '{"deadLetterTargetArn":"","maxReceiveCount":5}', 'MessageRetentionPeriod': '1209600', 'ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed': '0', 'MaximumMessageSize': '262144', 'CreatedTimestamp': '1415060940', 'ApproximateNumberOfMessages': '0', 'ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds': '20', 'DelaySeconds': '0',

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not guaranteed to get any messages in response when the queue size is small. This is a property of distributed queues. See [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you Jordon, this solved (partly) the issue. I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by this accepted answer, but it mislead a team member of mine.  The provided link never says we're not guaranteed to get any messages.  On the contrary, we are guaranteed "at least once" delivery by SQS.  There's no such thing as "in response" with SQS, so that's extra confusing.

Comment: @SamMefford looks like they moved around the docs and got the redirect wrong. Updated the link to its actual new location. Basically a message in a distributed queue is not guaranteed to be present on every node, and when you make a request for messages you're usually not sampling every node. Thus if there are a small number of messages in a queue there is a chance that none of the nodes you sample has one.

Comment: I concur with @SamMefford. It still doesn't add up to the promise of at least once delivery. Although, a distributed queue may not have a message replicated in all its nodes (yet to be replicated), it doesn't mean that the reader would fail to read the message. The consumer/client is not aware of which node the fetch is from and is irrelevant in this context to know that, as calls to access SQS are through a common entry point and not directed to a specific node.

Answer (score 2):

There were a couple of things at play here. For one thing, I was accidentally using a queue that was being read by another component (and deleting its messages). I was unaware of this. Also, Jordon's comment was also an issue since I was testing with one read at a time.